# Evaluate limit of $\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{x^x}{\left(x+2\right)^x}$

Tags: calculus, limits, exponential-function, limits-without-lhopital

$\lim_{x \to \infty}\dfrac{x^x}{\left(x+2\right)^x}$

I tried using Taylor and L'H and wasn't able to land on an answer.
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that as $x \to \infty$,
$$\frac{x^x}{\left(x+2\right)^x}=\left(\frac{x}{x+2}\right)^{x}=
\left(\frac{1}{1+\frac{2}{x}}\right)^{x}=\left(1+\frac{1}{x/2}\right)^{-x}=\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{x/2}\right)^{x/2}\right)^{-2}\to e^{-2}.$$
where we used the well-known limit
$$\lim_{t\to +\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{t}\right)^{t}=e.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! This really helped.

Comment: But can your clarify how you simplified the expression. I am having a hard time understanding how you turned $\dfrac{x^x}{\left(x+2\right)^x}$ into $\dfrac{1}{\left(\frac{2}{x}+1\right)^x}$ @Robert Z

Comment: @Abu Bakr Is it better now?

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You can take logarithms, which has the advantage that you do not have to recall well-known limits.

If 
$$L=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{x}{x+2}\right)^x$$
then
$$\ln L=\lim_{x\to\infty}x\,\left(\ln x-\ln(x+2)\right)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln x-\ln(x+2)}{\frac{1}{x}}$$
Can you take it from here?, e.g. L'Hôpital...

Answer (score 3):

For $x\rightarrow-\infty$ and for $x\rightarrow\infty$ your limit does not exist because the domain of $x^x$ is $(0,+\infty)$.

By the way, since $e^x$ and $\ln x$ are continuous functions, we obtain:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{x^x}{(x+2)^x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{x+2}-1\right)^{\frac{1}{\frac{x}{x+2}-1}\cdot\left(-\frac{2x}{x+2}\right)}=e^{-\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{2x}{x+2}}=e^{-2}=\frac{1}{e^2}.$$

Answer (score 3):

HINT: write $$\frac{1}{\left(\left(1+\frac{2}{x}\right)^{2x}\right)^{1/2}}$$

Comment: What is the limit of $(1+\frac 2x)^{2x}$? It seems to me that you wanted to write what Robert Z has written in his answer.

Comment: this Limit is $e^4$

Comment: Thank you for ignoring pragmatic implication.

Answer (score 3):

An approach with Taylor series. Let $f(x) = \frac{x^x}{(x+2)^x}$. Then,

\begin{align}
\ln f(x) = x\ln\left(1-\frac 2{x+2}\right)=x\left(-\frac{2}{x+2}-\frac 4{(x+2)^2}+\ldots\right)\stackrel{x\to +\infty}{\to}-2
\end{align}

which implies $\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x) = e^{-2}$.

EDIT:

As Miguel points out, it might be problematic to use the above technique, because what we really are using is not Taylor series, but Laurent series.

To avoid the issue, we could do as follows:

\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to +\infty} x\ln\left( 1-\frac 2{x+2} \right) &= \lim_{t\to 0^+}\frac 2 t\ln\left(1 -\frac 2{\frac 2t + 2} \right)\\
&= \lim_{t\to 0^+}\frac 2 t\ln\left(1 -\frac {2t}{2 + 2t} \right)\\
&= \lim_{t\to 0^+}\frac 2 t\ln\frac {1}{1 + t}\\
&= -2\lim_{t\to 0^+}\frac{\ln(1+t)}t = -2
\end{align}

Comment: Using the Taylor series at $x=0$ and then setting $x\to\infty$ requires a high degree of faith... even if it works :)

Comment: @Miguel, when $x$ is nearing infinity, $-2/(x+2)$ is sufficiently close to zero, why wouldn't Taylor work? I'll see if I can rewrite it in more transparent way.

Comment: I get why it works, it is just that proving formally that the series converge at $x\to\infty$ is well beyond Calculus I.

Comment: @Miguel, is my edit satisfactory?